# How to Fix AJAX Filtered Product List that does not render images in Django Ecommerce Project?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am trying to implement filter functionality in my e-commerce project. I ran into some problem when I generated filtered product list using **AJAX**, the products are all showing but images are not.

urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.store, name='home'),
    path('category/<slug:slug>', views.category, name='category'),
    path('product-detail/<int:id>', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    path('cart/', views.cart, name='cart'),
    path('checkout/', views.checkout, name='checkout'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('signin/', views.signin, name='signin'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('signout/', views.signout, name='signout'),
    path('filter-data/', views.filter_data, name='filter_data'),
]
```

views.py:

```py
def filter_data(request):
    category
    colors = request.GET.getlist('color[]')
    sizes = request.GET.getlist('size[]')
    all_products = Product.objects.all()
    
    if len(colors) > 0:
        all_products = all_products.filter(color__id__in=colors)
        print("All Products: ", all_products)
    
    if len(sizes) > 0:
        all_products = all_products.filter(size__in=sizes)
    
    ajax_template = render_to_string('ajax/product-list.html', {'products': all_products})
    return JsonResponse({"data": ajax_template})
```

ajax code:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/filter-data',
    data: _filterObj,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
        $(".ajaxLoader").show();
    },
    success: function (res) {
        console.log("This is res", res);
        $("#filteredProducts").html(res.data);
        $(".ajaxLoader").hide();
    }
});
```

Category.html *(This page holds all the products within the category)*:

```html
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9">
    <div class="row" id="filteredProducts">
        {% for product in products %}
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <div class="product__item">
                <div class="product__item__pic set-bg" data-setbg="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% endif %}">
                    {% if product.labels == 'sale' %}
                    <div class="label sale">{{ product.labels }}</div>
                    {% elif product.labels == 'bestseller' %}
                    <div class="label bestseller">{{ product.labels }}</div>
                    {% else %}
                    <div class="label new">{{ product.labels }}</div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <ul class="product__hover">
                        <li><a href="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% endif %}" class="image-popup"><span class="arrow_expand"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="icon_heart_alt"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="icon_bag_alt"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="product__item__text">
                    <h6><a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}">{{ product.name }}</a></h6>
                    <div class="rating">
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product__price">${{ product.price|floatformat:2 }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <div class="pagination__option">
                <a href="#">1</a>
                <a href="#">2</a>
                <a href="#">3</a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how [ajax/product-list.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CSZz.png) file looks.

After successfully sending and receiving data from the backend using **AJAX**, I thought it would work but it didn't.
Please let me know if I need to show more of my codes.

When I filter the products it does not show images, but the details of the products are being displayed. I will post some images to show it.

Before filtering:
[This image comes from database where category is Men](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwt7y.png)

After Filtering:
[This is after I filter size and colour from the front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwIPI.png)

Comment: Share the `ajax/product-list.html` template where you load the images after filtering.

Comment: Why don't you try to make your code more readable?

Comment: @Marco I have put it there as a screenshot.

Comment: @JacekBBudzynski Okay! I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud replace your `data-setbg="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% endif %}"` by `<img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% endif %}" alt="">`.

```html
<div class="product__item__pic set-bg">
  <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% endif %}" alt=""> 
  {% if product.labels == 'sale' %}
  <div class="label sale">{{ product.labels }}</div>
  {% elif product.labels == 'bestseller' %}
  <div class="label bestseller">{{ product.labels }}</div>
  {% else %}
  <div class="label new">{{ product.labels }}</div>
  {% endif %}
  <ul class="product__hover">
    <li><a href="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% endif %}" class="image-popup"><span class="arrow_expand"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon_heart_alt"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon_bag_alt"></span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```